# Q: index.js unexpected token (1:1)

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in several codepens:

```
<!-- Page scroll to top -->     
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('.top').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 800);
            return false;
        });
});
```

This worked for years, then maybe some 6 months ago, without having made any changes to my pens the js panel started displaying this error:

index.js: Unexpected token (1:1)

I can not find any reason for the error, nor how to correct it, but it often prevents the codepen page from loading. Codepen support was not able to help.

Here's one pen showing the error:

https://codepen.io/intermedion/pen/aIfhv

Any ideas what causes this error and how to correct it?

Comment: That first line, which is what it's complaining about (1:1 where the first one indicates the line, and the second 1 indicates the character), is an HTML comment, not a Javascript comment

Comment: Don't use HTML comments in JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your html comment from javascript:

html comment:

```
<!-- Page scroll to top -->
```

use instead a javascript comment:

```
// comment
or
/* 
 multiline comment
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use proper commenting on your js file.
use // or /* */.

// Page scroll to top

```
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $('.top').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 800);
                return false;
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about `index.js(1:1)` - the first character of the first line. That points to the comment:

`<!-- Page scroll to top -->`

The reason it's complaining is because this isn't valid javascript - it's an HTML comment. Removing it appears to resolve the issue, if you want to keep the comment then try:

`// Page scroll to top`